# Parsing XML with requests and ElementTree

Tags: xml, parsing, python-requests, elementtree

I'm trying to retrieve data from a scientific database. I had a working script with using urllib and ElementTree, but I wanted to use a more current module, so I tried to rewrite it with requests.

Unfortunatly ElementTree doesn't want to parse the XML anylonger due to an TypeError with unicode. So I tried BeautifulSoup instead, which works to some degree, but had issues with accessing nested tags. So back to ElementTree – which is inbuilt too.

For the following code I get "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Response found". If I add ".text" or ".content" to the line with et.parsing the error does not occur, but instead the whole site content is printed and not parsed.

```
for entry in input_list:
xml = requests.Session().get(url.xml)
if xml.status_code == 200:
    try:
        tree = et.parse(xml)
        root = getroot.tree()

        for record in root.iter(base + 'placeholder').text:
            var1 = record
            break

        print(var1)

    except TypeError:
        print('error on parsing')

else:
    xml.raise_for_status()
```

Edit:

The output should look like this with:

accession, name, protein recommendedName, gene name primary, NCBI Taxonomy, organism scientific, sequence, length

For the example this would be:

P0AES4, GYRA_ECOLI, DNA gyrase subunit A, gyrA, 83333, Escherichia coli (strain K12), MSDLAREITP..., 875

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: The URL is https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P0AES4.xml with P0AES4 being the unique id which is obtained from input_list. I want to receive certain values; e. g. gene name, description, reference links to other databases.

This xml behaves a bit strange, that’s why the root iteration includes the variable base {http://uniprot.org/uniprot}

Comment: Can you edit your question with a sample of your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem starts with **naming things properly**:

```py
xml = requests.Session().get(url.xml)
```

`requests.get()` does not return XML. It returns a *response*.

```py
resp = requests.Session().get(url.xml)
```

And this response might contain *text* (i.e. a string):

```py
print(resp.text)
```

And this string might be XML, which ElementTree can convert into a tree:

```py
tree = ET.fromstring(resp.text)
```

which we then can use to obtain information:

```py
tree.find('entry')
```

which returns None, because in this case the XML is in a namespace (xmlns="..."), and that namespace is `http://uniprot.org/uniprot`. We must mention that when we search for elements:

```py
tree.find('{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}entry')
```

which is unwieldy to write. So we make an abbreviation:

```py
xml_ns = {
    'up': 'http://uniprot.org/uniprot'
}
```

and use that instead:

```py
tree.find('up:entry', xml_ns)
```

which now prints

```
<Element '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}entry' at 0x03C0AD80>
```

Using all this, we get:

```py
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_url = 'https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P0AES4.xml'
xml_ns = {
    'up': 'http://uniprot.org/uniprot'
}

resp = requests.get(xml_url)
tree = ET.fromstring(resp.text)

def get_text(node):
    return node.text if node is not None else None

for entry in tree.findall('./up:entry', xml_ns):
    data = {
        'accession': get_text( entry.find('./up:accession', xml_ns) )
        # find and add more items
    }

    print(data)
```

which prints

```
{'accession': 'P0AES4'}
```

Comment: Thanks! The point with response wasn’t clear to me.

Can you explain two things a bit? 
1) What for is the `if node is not None else None` for? If the node already is `None` this leads again to `None`?
2) Why is the `xml_ns` neccessary every time, if we already set`'up'`?

Comment: @zyic 1) Correct. The difference is in what happens when the node is *not* none. 2) Yes, it's necessary every time you call `.find()` (or any of its cousins). It's better than the alternative of writing `'./{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}entry'` every time you call `.find()` - especially when the XPath gets longer.